# Non useful ORA error when working with KafkaConnect JdbcDriver with Oracle 11g (Strimzi Operator)

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using strimzi Kafka operator to work with a Confluent Cluster to achieve an Oracle2Kafka type KafkaConnector with JdbcSourceConnector from confluent.

The **KafkaConnector** spec

```
# connector 
connection.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE
connection.user: USER
connection.password: PASS
dialect.name: OracleDatabaseDialect
topic.prefix: test-topic-
mode: bulk
db.timezone: Europe/Madrid
table.whitelist: TEST_TABLE
```

But I get the following **error in the strimzi-cluster-operator** logs.

```
io.strimzi.operator.cluster.operator.assembly.ConnectRestException: PUT /connectors/confluent-cluster-int-20200706-02/config returned 400 (Bad Request): Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 43
 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:1534/***
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 43
 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:1534/***
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    at io.strimzi.operator.cluster.operator.assembly.KafkaConnectApiImpl.lambda$null$2(KafkaConnectApi.java:208) ~[io.strimzi.cluster-operator-0.18.0.jar:0.18.0]
```

If I modify the source I get a much specific stacktrace

```
2020-07-14 09:33:46,636 ERROR SQLException (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig) [qtp742672280-21]
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 43

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:451)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:552)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1292)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1025)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:223)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig$TableRecommender.validValues(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java:606)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig$CachingRecommender.validValues(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java:653)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:607)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:530)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validateAll(ConfigDef.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Connector.validate(Connector.java:135)
```

---

Some things I already checked

- **KafkaConnect** image is a self-made one with the required addons for the JdbcSourceConnector with an OracleDriver

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM strimzi/kafka:0.18.0-kafka-2.5.0
USER root:root
COPY ./kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.0.jar /opt/kafka/plugins/
COPY ./ojdbc6.jar /opt/kafka/libs/
USER 1001
```

- KafkaConnect resource is deployed successfully, as **KafkaConnect topics are being populated on confluent cluster** (connect-cluster-configs, connect-cluster-configs, ...)
- **Oracle driver seems to be successfully loaded**. If I add a typo in the credentials or connection chain the error is self-explanatory and makes sense. I also tried other versions of oracle drivers.
- Back in time (4 months ago), this same config was working (both on a local strimzi-deployed-cluster and confluent). Now the local cluster works fine, but confluent  one fails with the described error.
- Tried several upgraded latest versions of strimzi operator and kafka-jdbc-connector
- (edit) As suggested in strimzi slack, tried the `PUT /connector-plugins/JdbcSourceConnector/config/validate` rest endpoint of KafkaConnect and got same 2 errors, in the whitelist and blacklist fields

result

```
"value": {
  "name": "table.blacklist",
  "value": "",
  "recommended_values": [],
  "errors": ["Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1\nORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512: at line 43\n for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:1534/***"],
"visible": true
}
```

- (edit) I've tried to leave whitelist field empty and error is the same. The database seems not have been changed and the connection chain works fine from source code spring-data access.

I'm out of ideas, any hint is welcome x)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tools you use, but - the error you got means this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_var varchar2(1);       -- note length, only 1 character
  3  begin
  4    l_var := 'Littlefoot';   -- I'm little, but can't fit
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL>
```

What to do?

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_var varchar2(20);      -- is that enough?
  3  begin
  4    l_var := 'Littlefoot'; 
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.         --> Yes, it is!

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, check the *sizes* in your code.

Comment: yep, in a raw Oracle context, I already checked the meaning of that ORA error, but that makes no sense to a KafkaConnect that just queries a table, what's why I put the "non-useful ora error" in the title.; I'm trying to understand where that comes from..